# Is it possible to use switch case for more than one array.indexOf

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

I have some set of `if` conditions for a particular array using JavaScript.

`activity` is the array containing 10-12 items. This array is converted to a multiple select dropdown. Depending upon the value selected, I need to hide and show divs. I also need to set values of another input choice as "NA".

Here's the code written for the `onchange` of that multiple select dropdown.

```
activity = ["strategy session","sessions","virtual",...,"Other"]

if (activity.indexOf("strategy session") != -1) {
    $("#FoPStrategySession").show();
}

if (activity.indexOf("sessions") != -1) {
    $("#acprojectname").show();
    if (supportmodel == "Level") {
        $(".accombohide").hide();
        $("[title='Test']").val("NA");
        $("[title='Test2']").val("NA");
    }
}

if (activity.indexOf("virtual") != -1) {
    if (supportmodel == "Level") {
        $(".lvl3_consult").hide();
        $("[title='Test']").val("NA");
        $("[title='Test2']").val("NA");
    }
}

if (activity.indexOf("Other") != -1) {
    $("#acactivityother").show();
}
```

Is there any other way to **efficiently** write this code using switch case or any other method?

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: Can an `activity` contain multiple types you check for? For example, can `activity = ["sessions", "virtual"]`?

Comment: Can you provide more context here? What does this code actually do?  What does `activity` contain?  What is `supportmodel`?  If you need to, in essence, detect the presence of the value of "session", "virtual", etc. in the array, then I question whether an object with property names matching the values be used to allow direct O(1) lookup rather than having to iterate an entire array looking for the presence of the value.

Comment: I edited my question,hope you guys are clear now

Answer (score 2):

You could for example put all actions in an object

```
var actions = {
  "session": function() { console.log("session"); },
  "virtual": function() { console.log("virtual"); },
};
```

and loop over its keys:

```
var activities = [
    "session",
    "virtual",
    "other"
];

for(let i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
  let action = actions[activities[i]];
  if (action) action();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you might benefit from the approach of defining individual callbacks to do whatever DOM manipulation you need done for each of your option values.

That might look something like:

```
// configure your callbacks
var multiSelectCallbacks = {
    'acactivityother': function() {
        ("#acactivityother").show();
    },
    'virtual': function() {
        if (supportmodel == "Level") {
            $(".lvl3_consult").hide();
            $("[title='Test']").val("NA");
            $("[title='Test2']").val("NA");
        }
    },
    // etc.
}
```

To see this might be used, let's take a step back to where you bind your event handler for the dropdown menu (something you are not showing in your code)

That might need to look something like this:

```
$('#your_dropdown').on('change', function() {
    // get all selected options
    var selectedOptions = $(this).find('option:selected');

    // loop through selected options firing off callbacks
    $.each(selectedOptions, function() {
        var activity = $(this).val();
        multiSelectCallbacks[activity]();
    }
}
```